# Is there any way I could test a web active x plugin(addon) using cucumber-ruby

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir, bdd, watir-webdriver

I have to test an active x plugin, and I have tested a few sites with cucumber(still a beginner) so I was wondering if there's anyway I could test an active x plugin like the REST CLIENT on Mozilla using cucumber-ruby scripts

Answer (score 0):

if the way the client works is via a browser window, with stuff in the dom, I don't see why not.  (another similar approach would be the chrome 'postman' extension)

but the best answer is, try it and see.   Start by using right click and seeing if you get an 'inspect element' option, and what is shown if you use that should it be present.  If you can see the element in the DOM, then you can usually interact with it via watir-webdriver

Next start and IRB session,  get a browser object started

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.new :ff
```

then see if you can interact with it after manually navigating the page.  or try something like

```
b.goto 'chrome://restclient/content/restclient.html'
```

I will say this, if you intend to automate REST requests this way, you are doing it wrong.  tools like Rest Client and Postman are great for manual/exploratory testing of a rest api, and for debugging requests you are going to automate.  But for actual automation, go with a gem like [Rest-Client](http://rubygems.org/gems/rest-client) and code the requests directly in ruby, it will be MUCH faster.  If you want to use something like cucumber, and your rest requests are returning JSON, then also look into the [JSON-Spec](http://rubygems.org/gems/json_spec) gem as a way of doing far easier validation steps (also works with rspec)

Working directly that way is closer to how programmers using the API will work, and will execute far faster than driving a browser to generate the requests.

BTW "The Cucumber Book" has an example chapter on automating API tests this way. well worth reading